# Expand permutations string with SQL in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having difficulty even figuring out what to search for here so something of this sort may already have been answered.

I have a list of input strings that may include "expansion" characters. For example, `#` expands into each digit: `0123456789`. Let's say I have an input list like this:

```sql
WITH raw_input AS (
  SELECT 'apple#' AS item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '#banana#'   
)
```

Now what I'd like to achieve is a list of all possible outcomes with `#` replaced by digits. The end result of the above example would be ten apples (`apple0` through `apple9`) and <s>twenty</s> a hundred bananas (`0banana0` through `9banana9`).

What I have thought of thus far is to do some kind of `SPLIT` and then a `CROSS JOIN` but haven't made progress beyond the following and my brain is spent for the day:

```sql
WITH raw_input AS (
  SELECT 'apple#' AS item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '#banana#'   
), digits AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('0123456789', '')) AS digit
)

SELECT item, piece, digit
FROM raw_input
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(item, '#')) AS piece
LEFT JOIN digits ON piece = ''
```

I could just make a JavaScript UDF but I'm hoping for my own curiosity that I can solve this purely using BigQuery's [standard SQL functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators). And no, this isn't a school project.

Comment: 1) Can you clarify expected output for #banana#? why 20 rows? If you are looking for permutations - I would expected 10x10=100! 2) can you have more then 2 #'s? if yes - do you expect some limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

It actually applies permutation logic for all `#` found within the item and as you can see uses pure SQL (no use of JavaScript UDF)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE raw_input AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'apple#' AS item UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '#banana#' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '#ice#cream#'
); 

CREATE TEMP TABLE digits AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('0123456789', '')) AS digit
);

WHILE (SELECT COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(item, r'#')) FROM raw_input) > 0 DO 
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE raw_input AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM raw_input
    WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(item, r'#')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(item, r'(.*)#(.*)', r'\1' || digit || r'\2') AS item
    FROM raw_input, digits
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(item, r'#')
  );
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM raw_input ORDER BY id, item;
```

In above example - it will return 1110 rows: 10 for apple, 10x10=100 for banana and 10x10x10=1000 for ice cream

```
Row     id  item     
1       1   apple0   
2       1   apple1   
3       1   apple2   
4       1   apple3   
... 
11      2   0banana0     
12      2   0banana1     
13      2   0banana2     
14      2   0banana3     
... 
31      2   2banana0     
32      2   2banana1     
33      2   2banana2     
34      2   2banana3     
... 
1102    3   9ice9cream1  
1103    3   9ice9cream2  
1104    3   9ice9cream3  
... 
1109    3   9ice9cream8  
1110    3   9ice9cream9
```

Comment: I didn't realize there were control statements (`WHILE`) that I could use. This certainly has the output I'm looking for and doesn't use UDF's so I'm marking it as solved. I do think there's a possibility to do this in a single statement but I don't currently have the leisure to explore it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would think you would get 20 rows for banana.  But if you want 20 rows in total, then just use a `cross join`:

```
WITH raw_input AS (
      SELECT 'apple#' AS item
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '#banana#'   
     ),
     digits AS (
      SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('0123456789', '')) AS digit
     )
SELECT ri.item, d.digit, replace(ri.item, '#', d.digit)
FROM raw_input ri CROSS JOIN
     digits d
```

Comment: I made a mistake describing the bananas -- I meant 100 not 20 (added instead of multiplied). This solution unfortunately does not increment the numbers individually